# I'm having trouble implementing the fragment (imageButton) and make it work with my mainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on Android Studio, creating an ad, or banner for an existing application. I cannot use AdMob or anything similar. Therefore I created a fragment with an `ImageButton` that once I click on it takes me to a website. I am having issues trying to implement the `ImageButton` fragment.

`mainActivy.java`:

```
package com.android.nancysarmiento.assignmenttwo;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    ImageView pic;
    Button toggleBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pic =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        toggleBtn = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn));

    }
    public void toggleImage(View view){
        if(toggleBtn.getText().toString().equals("show me a nole")){
            pic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.nole);
            toggleBtn.setText("show me a gator");
            toggleBtn = (Button)(findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn));

       } else {
            pic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.gator);
            toggleBtn.setText("show me a nole");

        }
    }

}
```

`banner.java`

```
public class BannerAd extends Fragment {
    private static ImageButton bannerad;

    bannerSection activityCommander;

    public interface bannerSection {


    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner, container, false);

       bannerad = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.cs_ad);

       bannerad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.cs.fsu.edu/");
                       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                       uri);
                       startActivity(intent);
                   }
               }
       );

       return view;
   }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar; layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment is not started. Add this method to your Fragment NEW

```
public void startFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean on the mainActivity.java?